# R histograma com todas as breaks aparentes, função hist()

Tags: r, plot, histograma

Tenho uma base de dados com mais 8000 linhas e gostaria de criar um histograma, porém o mesmo não aparece a barra em todas as classes de menores frequências, no caso as últimas classes (Imagem).

Entendo que a 15º classe desaparece por apresentar apenas 1 ocorrência, quando comparado com a 1º classe que apresenta mais de 5mil.

Porém, existe algum método no r capaz de fazer essas classes aparecerem na imagem do gráfico?

Eu gostaria de fazer um histograma, com a função hist(), com essas mesmas classes, agrupadas de 10 em 10 como na imagem, aparecendo pelo menos uma barra mais escura nas classes de menor ocorrência (circulo vermelho na imagem)

[image: Histograma gerado, função hist()]

Alguns dados do histograma:

```
h1[["counts"]]
 [1] 5291 1657  728  324  158   69   46   18    8   10    5    6    1    0    1

h1[["breaks"]]
 [1]  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160
```

Tentei aumentar a quantidade de barras, porém quando passo o gráfico para png. algumas classes somem ou ficam muito pequenos, pois preciso plotar 5 destes graficos em uma imagem png.

Nessa configuração:

```
png(filename = "Figura1.png", width=620, height=1024,
    pointsize = 8, bg = "white", res = 120)

par(mfrow = c(5, 1), mar = c(4.5, 5, 1, 1) + 0.05)
```

Aumentando a quantidade de barras:

```
h0 = hist(x[,1], breaks = seq(min(x[, 1]) - 0.5, max(x[, 1]) + 0.5, by = 0.5))

h0$density = h0$counts/sum(h0$counts)*100 

plot(h0, freq = FALSE, main = " ")
```

Comment: Até onde você aumentou as dimensões do png?

Comment: plotei assim, width=620, height=1024, em uma matrix de 5 linhas e 1 coluna

Comment: Para quê `mfrow = c(5, 1)` se só tem uma figura? Isso define uma disposição de 5 gráficos, plotados por linhas primeiro. Como só há uma coluna e 5 linhas, podia também ser `mfcol`.

Comment: Porque irei plotar 5 gráficos mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o gráfico de barras é possível usar o log10 no eixo y, já com o histograma desconheço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

grafico_1 = ggplot(h1, aes(x=breaks, y=counts))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  xlab("Dados") + 
  ylab("Frequencia")


grafico_2 = ggplot(h1, aes(x=breaks, y=log10(counts)))+ 
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      xlab("Dados") + 
      ylab("Frequencia (log10)")

grid.arrange(grafico_1 , grafico_2 , ncol=2)
```